# openAI gym save data as times series

Tags: openai-gym

The openAI gym environments have the capability to print results to the screen and also render video. Is there a existing command or a wrapper/monitor that will save the time series data for the state and the actions? I would like to analyze the performance in the time-frequency domain.

I guess I could write the data to a file each time the animation is updated, but curious how others do this.

Answer (score 0):

What I found is this:

Gym wrapper which saves video and episode summary [here](https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/wrappers/monitor.py)

Code for how to use the wrapper [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52636899/python-openai-gym-monitor-creates-json-files-in-the-recording-directory)

If you also need to `save all actions and information` from each episode, I think you will have to create your own script.